# Consumir funciones jQuery desde otro archivo

Tags: jquery, funciones, cshtml

les comento, estoy intentando hacer una ''librería'' de funciones de jquery para no reutilizar tanto código, y para empezar, estoy intentando con la siguiente función.

```
jQuery.fn.soloNumerosDecimales = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;



            if (e.keyCode == 190 || e.keyCode == 110 || e.keyCode == 188) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
            }


            return (
                (key == 65 || key == 86 || key == 67) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true) ||
                key == 8 ||
                key == 9 ||
                key == 13 ||
                key == 46 ||
                key == 110 ||
                key == 190 ||
                (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
    });
};
```

La tengo sola en un archivo llamado **misFunciones.js**

Resulta, que al intentar consultarla desde jquery (en otro archivo, dentro de un cshtml) me da el siguiente error.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).soloNumerosDecimales is not a function
```

Intenté remplazarla por una función con la sintaxis

```
 function a(){
 alert("Hola");
 }
```

y no tuve ningun problema, la leyó correctamente.

Estoy intentando llamarla de la siguiente manera:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/misFunciones.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ref_primaria_positivo").soloNumerosDecimales();
});
```

Sin embargo, el navegador me dice que la función no existe, busqué mucho en internet, y no encuentro gente con este problema, alguien sabe a que puede deberse?

Muchísimas gracias de antemano!

**EDIT** 
Agrego la estructura de mi archivo.

**Cargo jquery, cldr y todo lo necesario para usar validate para Argentina

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js">
  </script>


<script>
     $.when(
    $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
    $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
    $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/numbers.json")
).then(function () {
    console.log("start slicing");
    return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
        console.log("slicing done");
        return result[0];
    });
}).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
    Globalize.locale("es-AR");
    console.log("Locale set to es-AR");
    }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));


</script>
```

Después viene algo de cshtml generado por Visual Studio (nada de js)

y ahí llega la parte del import y el jquery

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/misFunciones.js"></script>

  <script>

       $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ref_primaria_positivo").soloNumerosDecimales();


      });
  </script>
```

El archivo que incluyo 
      misFunciones.js
Tiene como único contenido la función que muestro arriba

Gracias chicos!

**EDIT:** olvidaba algo importante, y es que si declaro la función adentro del 
       
donde uso jQuery funciona perfectamente, el problema se da cuando quiero importarlo desde un .js externo.

Comment: Buen día hermano :D bienvenido a SOes, te invito a que pases por el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio (que al parecer ya lo conoces) y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Me late que el problema es porque en tu layout master jQuery está definido al final y tu función esta antes. ¿Podrías agregar a tu pregunta la estructura de dicho archivo y también la vista actual por favor? Un abrazo

Comment: que es showLinkLocation ?

Comment: @fredyfx Muchas gracias por la buena onda! jQuery lo incluyo al comienzo. Ahí edite la pregunta con el archivo casi completo, en cuanto a misFunciones.js es lo único que contiene el archivo, se te ocurre que podría ser? Gracias de nuevo :p

Comment: @WFgo Ahí lo arreglé, mala mía, era un intento que había echo que no funcionó, ahí pegué el error original

Comment: Ahí edite de nuevo, olvide mencionar, que el script me funciona bien siempre y cuando lo coloque dentro de <script></script> en el archivo, mi problema se da cuando quiero leerlo desde el .js misFunciones.js

Comment: de nada hermano, la buena onda siempre se transmite por estos lares, entre todos estamos colaborando para que SOes sea la hermandad más grande, importante e influyente en desarrolladores hispanos :D Sólo por curiosidad, ¿Has intentado quitar el document ready?

Comment: @fredyfx era eso ! ahora levantó la función! sos un genio :P

Comment: ¿sabes si sería posible usar este tipo de funciones dentro del document.ready de ser necesario? Justo en este caso, me solucionaste la vida :P pero pregunto por si se presenta dentro de poco :P

Comment: gracias hermano, dudo que sea genio... mi cuarto será chiquito pero no tanto como la lámpara de aladino xD!! (ok, mala broma), sólo intento cosas diferentes hasta que algo se rompe o algo se compone, una de dos :D Habrá que revisar la documentación del Document Ready de jQuery para entrar en detalles :D

Comment: Gracias por todo, ahí sabiendo que hacer para que funcione busque bien, y al parecer no es posible hacerlo así, nunca iba a funcionar :P

Comment: de nada hermano, sigue elevando ese cosmos y dale con todo el power 2.0!!! un abrazo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos sacando el document ready con una patada espartana :D

```
<script>

       //$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ref_primaria_positivo").soloNumerosDecimales();    

      //});

</script>
```